# Find the determinant by inspection

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm supposed to "use properties of determinants to evaluate the determinant by inspection" on this matrix: $$\pmatrix{ 0 & 0 & 3 \\ 0 & 4 & 1 \\ 2 & 3 & 1 }$$ I don't see anything (zero rows, ways to transform the matrix) that would make it immediately obvious what the determinant is. What am I missing?

Comment: What properties of determinants do you know / have you tried?

Comment: Also, Osama - welcome - I've changed your matrix into MathJax code. Please next time look at the bottom right of the "Ask Question" page for the link to this guide: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Perhaps the idea is the [Rule of Sarrus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus) which does indeed make the determninat obvious by inspection ($0+0+0-0-0-24=-24$)

Answer (score 4):

Interchange the first and third rows, which negates the determinant. Perhaps the matrix is now in a form that you recognize.

Answer (score 1):

Expand by cofactors along the top row. You willl be amazed at how little you must do!

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with the definition of the determinant using permutations, by staring at the matrix you can see that there is only one relevant permutation contributing a non-zero term to the sum and what is the sign of the permutation.

Answer (score 0):

Repeat the first two columns at the end:

$$\left[ \begin{array}{ccc|cc} 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 4 & 1 & 0 & 4 \\ 2 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 3 \end{array} \right] $$

The determinant is equal to the sum of the diagonal multiplications from the top minus the sum of the diagonal multiplications from the bottom, that is

$$ 0*4*1+0*1*2+3*0*3-(2*4*3+3*1*0+1*0*0)=-2*4*3=-24$$

It is easy to see the determinant right away because all but one of these multiplications are equal to $0$.